# CSV to JSON Function - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I am trying to write a function that converts CSV to JSON. A sample CSV looks like below:

```
"LNG,LAT,OBJECTID,NAME,ORGANIZATION,ZIP,PHONE,WEBSITE,DENTAL_PHONE,FULL_ADDRESS;
-75.164720995346343,40.034508187448395,1,Covenant House Health Services,Covenant,19144,215-844-0181,http://covenanthousehealth.org/,N/A,251 East Bringhurst Street;
-75.178981205302634,40.067382925736482,2,Mt. Pleasant Medical Center,Covenant,19150,215-248-7560,http://covenanthousehealth.org/,N/A,8125 Stenton Avenue;
-75.161411039978645,39.967025897357665,3,Fairmount Primary Care Center,DVCH,19130,215-235-9600,http://www.dvch.org/dvch/Locations/FairmountPrimaryCareCenter/tabid/100/language/en-US/Default.aspx,215-235-9600,1412 Fairmount Avenue;-75.18387328197538,39.953063560964601,4,Fairmount Primary Care Center at Horizon House,DVCH,19104,215-222-2466,http://www.dvch.org/dvch/Locations/FairmountPrimaryCareCenteratHorizonHouse/tabid/101/language/en-US/Default.aspx,N/A,120 S. 30th Street;
-75.162764718503027,39.971839944991942,5,Fairmount Primary Care Center at St. Josephs Hospital,DVCH,19130,215-827-8010,http://www.dvch.org/dvch/Locations/FairmountPrimaryCareCenteratStJosephs/tabid/134/language/en-US/Default.aspx,N/A,1600 W. Girard Avenue;
```

Below is my code:

```
  function CSV2JSON(CSV){
      var rows = CSV.split(';');
      var json = [];
      var header = rows[0].split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < CSV.length; i++) {

        var result = [];
        var CurrentRow = rows[i].split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
          result[header[j]] = CurrentRow[j];
        }


        json.push(result);

      }
    }
```

It keeps giving me the error saying that the split in var CurrentRow = rows[i].split(',') can't be read.

Can someone please tell me where the error is?

Thanks!

Comment: You're accessing `rows[i]`, but `i`, the index, is not bound by the length of `rows`. It rather is bound by the length of `CSV`, the input string. Where do you think the error is? Hint, what does indexing an array-out-of-bounds return, and what does trying to access a property on such a value raise?

Comment: Your for-loop with `i` should use `i < rows.length` not `i < CSV.length`